# Two-Way Dependency Property Binding with User Control

Tags: wpf

I have a simple User Control:

```
 public partial class FreqSpreadUC : UserControl
{
    public FreqSpreadUC()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();  
        FreqOne = "trying to pass this on to the parent";
    }

    public String FreqOne
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(FreqOneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FreqOneProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FreqOne.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FreqOneProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FreqOne", typeof(String), typeof(FreqSpreadUC));



}
```

Then I am consuming it as follows:

```
  <spread:FreqSpreadUC FreqOne="{Binding TestFreqOne}" />
```

When the underlying user control changes its FreqOne dependency property, I want TestFreqOne to change as well. I am trying to create a user control that will "output" a result to the parent control. How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and having `FreqOne` fire the event when `set` is called?

Comment: I did. Interestingly, adding the RelativeSource "<TextBox x:Name="testbox" Text="{Binding FreqOne, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"  />  Makes it work if i enter text and click out of the box(it will update to the parent control) but it doesn't work if I just change the property, even with inotify implemented.

Comment: you should update your question to show it with inotify implemented

Comment: @DLeh Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is not necessary on a dependency property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title already suggests it. You need a two-way binding:

```
<spread:FreqSpreadUC FreqOne="{Binding TestFreqOne, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Alternatively you might register property metadata with your dependency property that makes it bind two-way by default:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FreqOneProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FreqOne", typeof(String), typeof(FreqSpreadUC)
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: +1. It'd also be helpful to mention `BindsTwoWayByDefault` since I think that's what the OP really needs ;)

Comment: I added that before your post, but it seems to only change when my binded text box is edited and exited(thereby calling some underlying event). If I change my dependency property directly, it does not update the parent, even with the two way binding.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was unaware of BindsTwoWayByDefault.

Comment: @JohnEdwards Not sure which TextBox you are talking about, but the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for bindings on the `TextBox.Text` property is `LostFocus`. You may change that to `PropertyChanged` to upate any bound property immediately when the text changes.

Comment: I had a DataContext=this; That I forgot to remove that was keeping the TwoWay from working, which in turn made me think I was doing something else fundamentally wrong, even after changing it to TwoWay. Thank you!